# Subobject of a product

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In $\mathbf{Set}$, if $A$ and $B$ are nonempty sets, and $B'$ is a proper subset of $B$, then $A\times B'$ is a proper subset of $A\times B$. Is this true in any topos which is not degenerate? I mean, if $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos (not a degenerate topos), $A$ and $B$ are non-initial in $\mathcal{E}$ and $m:B'\rightarrowtail B$ is a subobject of $B$ which is not $1_B$ (or an isomorphism), then $1\times m:A\times B'\rightarrowtail A\times B$ is different from $1_{A\times B}$? If so, how to prove it? I have the impression it is true, but I'm not able to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: What about a case such as the topos is $\mathbb{R}$, $A = (-\infty, 0)$, $B = (0, \infty)$?  More generally, in topological spaces or Grothendieck sites, you could have $B'$ different from $B$ but the differences are concentrated away from the "support" of $A$.

Comment: What is the topos structure on $\mathbb{R}$ you're thinking of? I don't see it.

Comment: Shorthand for the category of sheaves of sets on $\mathbb{R}$.  (And then, for example, $A = (-\infty, 0)$ is shorthand for the object representing the functor of sections over $(-\infty, 0)$; this is the sheaf whose sections over $U$ are $\{ 0 \}$ if $U \subseteq (-\infty, 0)$ or $\emptyset$ otherwise.)

Comment: So, just to see if I'm getting it right, the answer is "they're not necessarily different", because, in the case you're mentionning, $A\times B=\emptyset$. The problem is that $A$ and $B$ have no elements; i. e., if $A$ and $B$ had at least one element, then $A\times B$ would not be initial.

Comment: It's true that in my example, $A \times B = \emptyset$.  But you need to be careful when you're talking about "elements" of an object of a general topos.  What's true in this case is that $A$ and $B$ have no *global sections*, i.e. $A(\mathbb{R}) = \emptyset$ and $B(\mathbb{R}) = \emptyset$.  (In a general topos, the global sections of an object $A$ in general can be defined as the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(1, A)$ where $1$ is the final object of $\mathbf{C}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.  Here are some counterexamples:

- The topos is the "two point topos" $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$, $A = (\{ 0 \}, \emptyset)$, $B = (\emptyset, \{ 0 \})$, $B' = (\emptyset, \emptyset)$.
- The topos is the category of sheaves of sets on $\mathbb{R}$, $A = h_{(0, 2)}$, $B = h_{(1, 3)}$, $B' = h_{(1, 2)}$.  (Here, if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $h_U$ is the unique sheaf whose sections over $V$ are $\{ 0 \}$ if $V \subseteq U$, or $\emptyset$ otherwise.  You can then check that there is a unique isomorphism $h_U \times h_V \simeq h_{U\times V}$.)

What you *can* prove is: if there exists some test object $X$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(X, A) \ne \emptyset$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B') \ne \operatorname{Hom}(X, B)$ (where we treat $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B')$ as being a subset of $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B)$ via composition with the given monomorphism $B' \hookrightarrow B$), then $A \times B' \ne A \times B$.

Inversely, if for every $X$ in some *generating set* of the topos, we have that either $\operatorname{Hom}(X, A) = \emptyset$ or $\operatorname{Hom}(X, B') = \operatorname{Hom}(X, B)$, then $A \times B' = A \times B$.  (Then in the case of the topos being the category of sheaves of sets on some topological space $S$, and the generating set being the set of $h_U$ for $U \subseteq S$ open, this reduces to: if for every $U$, either $A(U) = \emptyset$ or $B'(U) = B(U)$, then $A \times B' = A \times B$.  Similar statements would work for a category of presheaves of sets, or for a category of sheaves on a Grothendieck site.)

---

I don't know if your treatment of topos theory includes anything about the internal language.  If so, then one possible statement you can make about equality of a product in an intuitionistic type theory would look something like:

$$A : Type, B : Type, B' : P(B) \vdash (Full_A \times B' = Full_A \times Full_B) \leftrightarrow [(\exists x:A, \top) \rightarrow B' = B].$$

Comment: What is a test object? I mean, is that name for an object with a special property? Or is it just an object? (A test category is a special category.)
Within the internal language part, I don't know how to read this `$(\exists x:A,\top)$' fragment. It's $x$ is of type $A$, but what is the meaning of the whole thing?

Comment: A test object is just any arbitrary object of the category.  I just tend to call $X$ a "test object" when I use $\operatorname{Hom}(X, -)$ to test for certain categorical properties.  For example, a morphism $h : A \to B$ is a monomorphism if and only if for each "test object" $X$ in the category, the set function $h \circ - : \operatorname{Hom}(X, A) \to \operatorname{Hom}(X, B)$ is injective.  This is the basis of a strategy that allows you to take many "diagram chasing" style arguments which work in a category of sheaves, and generalize them to work in an arbitrary topos.

Comment: As for $\exists x : A, \top$, there $\top$ is the true proposition, and $\exists$ is the existential quantifier.  So $\exists x : A, \top$ says that there exists an element of the type $A$.  (Which in intuitionistic type theory is distinguished from the proposition that $A$ is nonempty: in fact, $A$ being nonempty is the double negation of the proposition that an element of $A$ exists.)

Comment: (So, where in set theory you would write $\exists x \in A, \phi(x)$, in type theory some authors will instead write $\exists x : A, \phi(x)$.)